# Ionic Pull to Refresh (Refresher) Inside an Element

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

Is it possible to implement [Ionic's pull to refresh (aka "Refresher")](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/refresher/Refresher/) inside of an element instead of on an entire page?

This would be useful when designing an app that has a smaller scrollable section within a page. With the current behavior, the entire page is pulled down rather than just the scrollable element.

Answer (score 7):

Actually you can do this, but it is more a workaround than a really nice solution.
`ion-refresher` components can only be used in `ion-content`.

So you are able to put another `ion-content` in your page.

```
<ion-content padding>
    <div>
        <!-- Your other content -->
    </div>

    <!-- Additional ion-content -->
    <ion-content>
        <!-- Your inline ion-refresher -->
        <ion-refresher></ion-refresher>
    </ion-content>
</ion-content>
```

You need to put every `ion-refresher` into a new `ion-content`, because the `ion-refresher` component will be put at the end of the `scroll-content` container, that is generated in `ion-content`.

Just note, **that you wont be able** to use a full page `ion-refresher` with an in page `ion-refresher`, because both will be executed, when you try to pull the in page `ion-refresher`:

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-refresher></ion-refresher>

    <!-- Your other content -->

    <ion-content>
        <ion-refresher></ion-refresher>
    </ion-content>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do by using ion-scroll. The sample code given below:

```
<ion-content>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="col-sm-12">This text will display on top</p>
    </div>

    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ion-scroll>
              <ion-refresher>
              </ion-refresher>
              <p class="col-sm-12">This text will be under ion-refresher pull refresh</p>
            </ion-scroll>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p class="col-sm-12">This text will display on center right</p>
        </div>    
    </div> 
    <div class="row">
        <p class="col-sm-12">This text will display on bottom</p>
    </div>
<ion-content>
```

Also please check the image, only blue content portion will be under ion-refresher. Other section will be outside the refresher.

[image]

Comment: ion-scroll is not a known element in Ionic 4. Seems like ion-refresher only work within ion-content. But having ion-content inside another ion-content seems to disturb the layout, causing no content being displayed.

Comment: @Sem, the question is tagged under ionic2 and ionic3, its not for ionic4.

Comment: Ok, but is there any solution for Ionic 4?? I can't believe we can't decide which element is the parent yet :|

Comment: @Jahrenski, I can't understand your requirements. Please explain more clearly.

Comment: @I. Ahmed, if we could set an input value to the Ionic 4's ion-refresher to a custom parent element (such as a div) instead of ion-content, all of this would be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried **ion-scroll** inside **ion-content** in your section and put the refresher inside ?

Comment: check solutions above, there a using this

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<div id='smaller-scrollable-section'>

    <ion-content>

        <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
            <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
        </ion-refresher>

        <ion-list>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let item of collection">
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>

        <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="fetchMore($event)">
            <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
        </ion-infinite-scroll>

    </ion-content>

</div>
```